# como pegar valores específicos através de hashmap

Tags: java

Gente, tenho esse código. O que ele faz:  **ele serve para contar quantos segundos eu demoro pra digitar uma frase, nesse caso, 'tecnologia'.** Porém, como a intenção é imitar um teclado, esse teclado vai bloquear algumas letras que pelo nosso dicionário não tem como ficar juntas, ou melhor, não tem como formar uma palavra. Por exemplo, ao digitar 'Z', é super lógico que o teclado tenha que bloquear a letra 'B', já que vai ser difícil encontrar uma palavra que depois do 'Z' venha o 'B'.

No caso do código está a palavra 'TECNOLOGIA' e esse teclado deveria bloquear algumas teclas para cada letra específica e consequentemente não "passar" por essas letras bloqueadas. Por exemplo:
ao digitar a **letra 'T'** deve-se deixar "ativas", ou melhor, contáveis, apenas as letras: A,C,E,H,I,O,P,R,S,U,V,W.
A **letra 'E':** todas as letras devem ficar ativas;
A **letra 'C':** deve-se deixar "ativas" apenas as letras: A,C,E,F, H,I,K,L,,M,N,O,S,T,U;
A **letra 'N':** deve-se deixar "ativas" apenas as letras:A,E,I,O;
A **letra 'O':** deve-se deixar "ativas" apenas as letras:C,O,L,P,R;
A **letra 'L':** deve-se deixar "ativas" apenas as letras:O;
A **letra 'O':** deve-se deixar "ativas" apenas as letras:G;
A **letra 'G':** deve-se deixar "ativas" apenas as letras:I;
A **letra 'I':** deve-se deixar "ativas" apenas as letras:A;

Eu gostaria de saber como pode ser implementado ou se é possível implementar, se é possível fazer essa contagem!?

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ContagemAutoComplete {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashLetras=new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    hashLetras.put("A", 2); hashLetras.put("B", 3); hashLetras.put("C", 4); hashLetras.put("D", 5); hashLetras.put("E", 3);

    hashLetras.put("F", 4); hashLetras.put("G", 5); hashLetras.put("H", 6); hashLetras.put("I", 4); hashLetras.put("J", 5);

    hashLetras.put("K", 6); hashLetras.put("L", 7); hashLetras.put("M", 8); hashLetras.put("N", 9); hashLetras.put("O", 5);

    hashLetras.put("P", 6); hashLetras.put("Q", 7); hashLetras.put("R", 8); hashLetras.put("S", 9); hashLetras.put("T", 10); 

    hashLetras.put("U", 6); hashLetras.put("V", 7); hashLetras.put("W", 8); hashLetras.put("X", 9); hashLetras.put("Y", 10);

    hashLetras.put("Z", 11); hashLetras.put(" ", 7); //ESPACO

    String teste="TECNOLOGIA";

    int count=0;

    for(int i=0; i<teste.length();i++){

        if( i<(teste.length()-1) && teste.charAt(i)=='Q' && teste.charAt(i+1)=='U'){
             count = count+7;
             i++;
        }else{
            String c = teste.charAt(i)+ "";
            System.out.println("LETRA:"+ c);
            count = count+hashLetras.get(c);
            System.out.println("NUMERO DA LETRA:"+ hashLetras.get(c));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("O tempo foi de: "+count);
}
}
```